# Image.FromFile and picturebox won't display image from computer

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using Winforms and have a picturebox. When the user clicks on it, I want to load a image from my computer. But its not working. Any ideas why?

```
 private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:/wamp/www/cyber.jpeg");
     pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(@"C:\wamp\www\cyber.jpeg");
 }
```

If I click on it, I get the error "FileNotFoundException was unhandled". If I remove the Image.FromFile and use the Bitmap instead, I get the error "Parameter is not valid"

Comment: Do you have the file Extension `.jpeg` or `.jpg` check.

Comment: So, it is obvious, your file name and/or file path is wrong!

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\wamp\www\cyber.jpeg");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your filepath is correct , I think You have `.jpg` as extension for your image but you are trying to access with extension `.jpeg`

Try This:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:/wamp/www/cyber.jpg");
```